# How would the UA Theurgy wizard's Channel Arcana: Divine Arcana feature work for a concentration spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, unearthed-arcana, concentration

The [UA Theurgy Wizard](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/MJ320UAWizardVF2017.pdf) can the apply their Divine Arcana Channel Arcana option to grant themselves a +2 to the attack roll or spell save throw DC of a spell.

If they apply Divine Arcana to a concentration spell that requires a saving throw, does it add +2 to the saving throw DC for the entire duration of the spell, or only on the turn the spell is cast?

I'm just wondering, because the Sorcerer's Heightened Spell Metamagic option only applies to one saving throw on a single creature, but this could apply every round to every creature in a spell's effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It adds it to the DC save for the duration

When the DC is set for the spell, [Theurge Wizard](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/MJ320UAWizardVF2017.pdf) (UA, 2017) can use their Channel Arcana: Divine Arcana, which states that:

> The next spell you cast gains a +2 bonus to...its saving throw DC...

That bonus affects the total save DC of the spell. It doesn't matter if it's concentration, non-concentration, single target, or multiple target. It's just the total save DC and it applies as normal once calculated.

### A note on Unearthed Arcana

The point you bring up may be very true regarding comparison against the Sorcerer's metamagic.

UA is still playtest and there may be aspects of this class that need to be tweaked. If you/your DM feel that something just is over/underpowered, you may wish to adjust during play based on experience. WoTC may not tweak or even update this class, so if you see something, change something.